# How secure are hidden authenticity tokens in twitter's oauth clients' web UI?

Tags: web-services, security, ssl, twitter, cryptography

Assuming that you already have created an oauth client app in twitter, you can go to http://twitter.com/apps to manage them. When I viewed the source of the HTML pages, I see that they use a hidden form parameter called an authenticity token in their form definitions.

```
<form method="post" id="sign_out_form" action="/sessions/destroy" style="display:none;"> 
<input name="authenticity_token" value="18c9957agd7ysdjgsgd87sgdjs" 
  type="hidden"/> 
</form>

<form action="/oauth_clients/regenerate_keys/299120" id="regenerate_keys_form" 
 method="post" style="float: right;">  
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
 value="18c9957agd7ysdjgsgd87sgdjs" />
 <input type="submit" id="regenerate_keys" value="Reset Consumer Key/Secret"     
class="btn"/> 
</form>
```

Given that the whole web page is accessed via SSL, what is the basis for these authenticity tokens? They never change; thus they are not nonces. Can someone enlighten me on their utility ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a standard feature of Rails (which Twitter's front-end is written in). The authenticity token is a random string generated per session, and is used to guard against [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You can read more about the attack vector and why Rails uses the authenticity token on the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). An app being served fully under SSL wouldn't prevent a CSRF attack; the purpose is simply to ensure that when a POST/PUT/DELETE is made to a resource, it is done so from a form generated by the application, and which has been seen in some form by the user.

Comment: Sounds very similar to javascript's same origin limitation.

Comment: It's not quite the same thing, but it accomplishes much of the same goal.